# How do you identify a result based on counting two criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to identify all StudentID's that have more than one of the same IncidentCode, but only if the IncidentID is also > 1.  How do I do this please?

**Dataset:**

[image]

**Desired Result:**

[image]

Sample dataset code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Duplicates(
IncidentID varchar(10),
StudentID varchar(10),
IncidentCode varchar(10),
Levels varchar(10)
)
INSERT into #Duplicates (IncidentID, StudentID, IncidentCode, Levels)
VALUES 
('1', '4444444','06','1'),
('1', '4444444','06','2'),
('23', '5555555','06','1'),
('22', '3333333','06','2'),
('64', '3333333','06','2'),
('64', '3333333','06','3')

SELECT * 
FROM #Duplicates
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Distinct * 
FROM #Duplicates
Where IncidentID in (Select IncidentID from #Duplicates Group By IncidentID  having count(*)>1)
```

Returns

```
IncidentID  StudentID   IncidentCode    Levels
1           4444444     06              1
1           4444444     06              2
64          3333333     06              2
64          3333333     06              3
```

Comment: Thank you @John Capelletti. This did return the results I asked in the original question. I changed the question to better reflect what I'm after,  I need to see students with more than 1 of the same IncidentCode, with the same Incident ID.  Does this make sense?  Do I need to ask a new question, or change this one?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use join also:it will help you in performance if you are dealing with huge data

```
SELECT * 
FROM #Duplicates a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT incidentID FROM #Duplicates b 
GROUP BY incidentID HAVING COUNT(incidentCode)>1) b ON a.IncidentID = b.IncidentID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use query like this

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY studentid ORDER BY incidentcode) AS rn
FROM #Duplicates
WHERE IncidentID > 1)
SELECT DISTINCT
    StudentId
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select D2.*
from Dataset D2
inner join (   

select StudentID, count(incidentCode)
from Dataset
where IncidentID >1
group by StudentID
having count(incidentCode) >1
) A1
on A1.StudentID = D2.StudentID
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @JohnHC.  However, this gives me an error: "No column name was specified for column 2 of 'A1'".